# JSON Array to Java object in Spring Data Elasticsearch getting Null value

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using Java with spring-data-elasticsearch version 2.1.0

Every field except the customList works fine. customList in java is getting a null value everytime.

My JSON:

```
{
"Id": "123",
"customList": {
    "Item 1": [
        {
            "name": "xyz",
            "price": "15"
        },
        {
            "name": "qwe",
            "price": "11"
        }
    ],
    "Item 2": [
        {
            "name": "abc",
            "price": "20"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to deserialize this json in class A:

```
@Document(indexName = "repository", type = "sop")
public class A {

  @Id
  private String Id;
  @Field(type = FieldType.Nested)
  private Map<String, List<B>  > customList;
}

public class B {
  private string name;
  private string price;
}
```

Deserialized object of A

```
{
  "id": "123",
  "List": null
}
```

Can anyone please give a reason why this array is not deserializing and what can be done to correct it.

Comment: Spring Data Elasticsearch 2.1.0 is an old version and is out of maintenance. You should use an actual version of Spring Data Elasticsearch and Elasticsearch itself.

Comment: Still, in the new version, I needed to replace transport client with RestHighLevelClient.
But the mapping thing remains the same and it is still reading null value in customList.

Comment: Is there any way to define a custom mapping? I am new to this all so I don't know how to do this and couldn't find any documentation for it. @P.J.Meisch

Comment: Do you have getter/setter for your objects? Using the sample classes works for me with Spring Data Elasticsearch 4. But beware that using a map here will incraese the mappings for your index with every new document you store that has a new customList key